# ASP.NET Wizard control, how to add a step dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, wizard

Code-behind:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        var t = new TemplatedWizardStep { Title = "Lalalal" };
        t.Controls.Add(new Step1UserControl());
        _WizardWebControl.WizardSteps.Add(t);
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
}
```

Page markup:

```
<asp:Wizard runat="server" id="_WizardWebControl">
```

Step1UserControl.ascx markup:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>General Informations</legend>
     <p>TEST DYNAMIC</p>    
</fieldset>
```

The step show at the left bar with the Title, but the HTML (fieldset and the paragraph) is not displayed in the step. It requires to be a TemplatedWizardStep too because we use Template for the layout. How do I add a Step dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this way is the best practice, but it works:

Step1UserControl should implement ITemplate interface,

```
public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
{
    container.Controls.Add(this);
}
```

and then onInit may look like this:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    TemplatedWizardStep templatedWizardStep =  new TemplatedWizardStep { Title = "Lalalal" };

    //  load control by path to initialize markup
    ITemplate control = (ITemplate)Page.LoadControl("\\Step1UserControl.ascx");                        
    
    templatedWizardStep.ContentTemplate = control;            
    wizard.WizardSteps.Add(templatedWizardStep);
    
    //  make it visible
    wizard.MoveTo(templatedWizardStep);
    base.OnInit(e);   
}
```